# How to get the last digit in each row in a number series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that contains many data. One column named 'x' (the most relevant), contains numbers and I want to get just the last digit to then operate if it meets the condition.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':[500, 200, 100],
                   'x':[125, 129, 349]})

   value    x
0    500  125
1    200  129
2    100  349
```

Once having the data frame, I want to check if the last digit inside the value 'x' is 5 and if so then multiply by 2 the column 'value' and if not, don't do any operation. The end result should be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'value':[500, 200, 100],
                    'x':[125, 129, 349],
                    'value2':[1000, 200, 100]})

   value    x  value2
0    500  125    1000
1    200  129     200
2    100  349     100
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's do some math: (i.e. if the number ends with 5 then the modulo division by `10` will always yield `5`)

```
df['value2'] = df['value'].mask(df['x'] % 10 == 5, df['value'] * 2)
```

---

```
   value    x  value2
0    500  125    1000
1    200  129     200
2    100  349     100
```

Comment: Ah yes, you're right that pandas' generic `.mask`/`.where` is better here, where one of the values doesn't actually need to change.

Comment: @BeRT2me To be honest I think `np.where` should outperform `mask/where` on very large datasets :-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, I have another escenario, what if I want the same operation but add another, I mean, in addition on multiply by 2 those values who finishes with 5, what if I want tu multiply by 4 those who finishes with 9?

Comment: In that case `% 10 == 9` would work.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an integer ends with 5, we can look at its mod 10 value, then use `np.where` to choose conditions.

```
df['value2'] = np.where(df.x.mod(10).eq(5), df.value.mul(2), df.value)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   value    x  value2
0    500  125    1000
1    200  129     200
2    100  349     100
```